# Django deploying website

Tags: python, django, production

I have made a website with django. I want to deploy this application to production.

Now I am confused about several things: at the time of the development I can run my application using the command: `python manage.py runserver IP_OF_SERVER:PORT`. 
Now by this approach I can do everything. My tool (website) will only be used locally.
Is it fine that I deploy my website with this command only? Is is necessary to do django production processes and if it is necessary how to do that? I am new to django. Please help me to understand.

Comment: If you just need the project locally, using this method is fine.

Comment: Depending on setup we serve a Django Application with Apache and mod_wsgi on Ubuntu

Comment: Glenn Sampson :Why apache and mod_wsgi is required?Is this commendatory for local deployment?Please give your thoughts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, these kinds of things are deployed in a [three tier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Web_development_usage) fashion.

Here, the general approach is like so

```
[Database] <-(db calls)-> [Django app] <- wsgi -> [gunicorn] <- http -> [nginx] <- http -> public
```

your application is the "Django app" block over here. You could run it with something like `manage.py runserver` but that's a very lightweight toy server which can't really handle high levels of traffic. If you have a request that takes 1ms to handle and 100 users try to make the same request, the last client will have to wait 100ms before she can get the response. It's easy to solve this by just running more instances of your application but the dev server can't do that.

A so called "app server" like gunicorn will allow you to run a more powerful web server for your application that can spawn off multiple workers and handle some kinds of mischievous traffic patterns.

Now, even gunicorn can be bested by a high performance server especially for serving static assets like images, css, js etc. This is something like nginx. So, we set up our thing to have nginx facing the world and serving all static assets directly. And request to the actual application will be proxied to gunicorn and that will be served by your actual app.

This is not as complex as it sounds and you should be able to get something running within a day or so. All the technologies I've mentioned have substitutes with different characteristics. [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/) is a good tutorial on how to get things going and what to look out for during deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.So manage.py runserver can't handle multiple clients at a time?

Comment: Nope. You can try it. Stick a `sleep(10)` or something similar in a view and then try to hit two URLs at once.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my droughts.As of my understanding we need to do production configuration(wsgi etc.) so that multiple client requests can be processed at a time.

Comment: That's one of the reasons. You might also want to load balance multiple Gunicorns etc. The inbuilt web server is just for development use. There are many real world conditions it can't handle.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup your Django production server through IIS in Windows server (If users are less, you can even use normal Windows 7 or 10 professional machines as well). This video can help you do it step by step

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXbfHtAvubc

I have brought up couple of production websites this way.

Although the one you are trying to do also works, but the only problem with your approach is that you should take care that console is never closed by anyone or you accidentally. But there are lot more hidden problems, usually for production, this is not recommended.

To avoid accidental closures, you can do below in Windows (running it as a service):

For this approach, you need pywin32 needs to be installed, install it from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20217/

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32event
import subprocess
import os

class PySvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

    # you can NET START/STOP the service by the following name
    _svc_name_ = "Name your Service here"
    # this text shows up as the service name in the Service
    # Control Manager (SCM)
    _svc_display_name_ = "External Display Name of your service"
    # this text shows up as the description in the SCM
    _svc_description_ = "Description what this service does"

    def __init__(self, args):
        import platform
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        # create an event to listen for stop requests on
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    # core logic of the service
    def SvcDoRun(self):
        os.chdir('your site root directory')
        subprocess.Popen('python manage.py runserver IP:PORT')
        # if you need stdout and stderr, open file handlers and keep redirecting to those files with subprocess `stdout` and `stderr`

    # called when we're being shut down
    def SvcStop(self):
        # tell the SCM we're shutting down
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)

        # fire the stop event
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PySvc)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.We can put python manage.py runserver IP_OF_SERVER:PORT in some start up script so if the server starts then this command will be automatically executed in background and nobody can close that console.Is this fine?

Comment: yes, you can PySVC module to run it as server in the background as well. Let me add that method as well to the answer